# ggplot geom_bar can I highlight a bar in different color if value is above a threshold

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I use ggplot and geo_bar to produce a plot, results is this:

[image]

Code

```
# Faceting is a good alternative:
ggplot(df.cnts, aes(x=date,y=freq)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  facet_wrap(~ operator, nrow = 3) +
  theme(axis.text.x  = element_text(angle=90, vjust=0.5, size=8))
```

Question

Can I have code that colors all bars in which the value is above 1000.

thx

Comment: You should include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with your question with sample data so we can run the same code as you to test possible answers. Have you tried setting a `color=` aesthetic at all? `geom_bar(aes(color=freq>1000), stat="identity")`?

Comment: You can embed an ifelse statement in aes(fill=) - that may do what you want.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
mt_mean <-   mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise(avg_mpg = mean(mpg) )  

ggplot( mt_mean , aes(x=cyl, y =avg_mpg)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity', aes(fill = avg_mpg > 25 )  ) 

g + scale_fill_manual(values = c('red', 'black') )
```

Comment: You don't need the `ifelse` except for labeling... `fill = avg_mpg > 25` works fine

Comment: Thanks - didn't realize that. You could label in `scale_fill_manual`